# The last unmovable file appears to be: \$BadClus:$Bad:$DATA

Tags: windows-7

As I mentioned in a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/170725/the-last-unmovable-file-appears-to-be-pagefile-sys), I'm trying to shrink my primary hard drive to split it into another partition. I'm getting the following message as a result.

> The last unmovable file appears to be:
>   \$BadClus:$Bad:$DATA

Is there any way to move this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has certain files that are unmovable while you are booted into the OS, I would try defragging and compacting the files by connecting the hard drive to another PC and running a complete defrag of the offline drive. Then put it back in the original PC and try the shrink again.

Another method to use is a third party partitioning tool from a boot disk.

Comment: +1; and I'd like to suggest a 3rd party tool - GParted from a Live CD. I once used exactly that to punt an entire Vista partition along by ~200Gb to make space for Win7 at the start of the disk. It took *ages*, but did the job. Just be careful...

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't do anything with it.  It's a list of bad pieces of the disk.  Since it represents a physical reality there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would run spinrite.  The hard drive is capable of logically swapping out bad sectors like the one in the error.  I had the same problem where I couldn't resize a partition.

You could always make an image backup, reformat, reimage, and then do the move.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game, but I had this happening on a PC this week.

My solution was to:

1. boot the GParted live CD http://gparted.org/livecd.php
2. start GParted in UI mode (you might want to use the safe mode which uses the VGA screen drivers)
3. find out which device (like `/dev/sda4`) your partition is on
4. clean the bad sector markings from a terminal using the command `sudo ntfsfix -b /dev/sda4`
5. boot into Windows
6. through an administrative command prompt, force a checkdisk on the drive `chkdisk E: /F` (reboot if Windows asks for it)
7. shrink the partition (I used UltraDefrag and MyDefrag for this)
8. resize using the `diskmgmt.msc`
9. allocate a new NTFS partition with a new drive letter (for instance `X:`) on it
10. on an administrative command prompt, verify for bad sectors (`chkdsk X: /B`) which can take a few hours.

I got the fix steps via https://askubuntu.com/questions/403434/removing-a-bad-sector-from-an-ntfs-partition-badblocks-gave-me-an-output-now-w/403490#403490